# How to add multiple(but specific) posts to different areas in one page?

Tags: posts

I'm building my own theme, but I can't understand something. If I want to have something like this in index.php file:

```
//getting header with get_header() - not important
...some code...
//and here I want to add some specific post from specific category(ONLY this specific post)
...some other code...
//another specific post from specific category(only this specific post again).
...some another code...
//and so on
//getting footer with get_footer() - not important
```

How do I do it in the most right way, so it will not go in the conflict with each post(because it's on the same page) and how do I request only once and not many times(perhaps I'm confusing this with something else, I'm new) so the requests for the database will be as little as possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with different techniques-

1. One of them is with `get_posts()` function. You can pass parameter inside it and get an array of specific posts. Then you've to run a `foreach` loop to show those posts as you want.
2. And you can also use `WP_Query()`. It also takes parameter like `get_posts()` but after every query you need to reset the query with `wp_reset_query()`.

For first case-

```
//getting header with get_header() - not important
...some code...
//and here I want to add some specific post from specific category(ONLY this specific post)
$args_1 = [
    'category__in' => 1 // category id
];
$posts_1 = get_posts( $args_1 );

foreach ($posts_1 as $post_1){
    // show posts as you want
}
//another specific post from specific category(only this specific post again).
$args_2 = [
    'category__in' => 2 // category id
];
$posts_2 = get_posts( $args_2 );
foreach ($posts_2 as $post_2){
    // show posts as you want
}
//and so on
//getting footer with get_footer() - not important
```

For second case-

```
//getting header with get_header() - not important
...some code...
//and here I want to add some specific post from specific category(ONLY this specific post)
$args_1 = [
    'category__in' => 1 // category id
];
$posts_1 = new WP_Query( $args_1 );
while ( $posts_1->have_posts() ) : $posts_1->the_post();

    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.


endwhile; // End of the loop.
wp_reset_query();
//another specific post from specific category(only this specific post again).
$args_2 = [
    'category__in' => 2 // category id
];
$posts_2 = new WP_Query( $args_2 );
while ( $posts_2->have_posts() ) : $posts_2->the_post();

    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.


endwhile; // End of the loop.
wp_reset_query();
//and so on
//getting footer with get_footer() - not important
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do you put a specific post in there?

Comment: For specific post you can use `get_post( $post_id )` function. It will return you a post object.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/ .  If this answer helps you, please accept it. @makovar

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean accept it? Of course it help! :) And please tell me, are this both approaches are the same in terms of database requests? How can I tell how many request are there?

Comment: See left side of my answer there is right sign for accepting the answer. Please click there to accept the answer.

Comment: I've not understood you question about request. Can you please make it more clear ?

Comment: Well, it's like HTTP requests... But only for database. I think. Not sure, but something like this.

Comment: HTTP is a different thing. It actually running two queries and resetting after each one. That's it. By the way have you found the way for answer accepting ? If not the visit this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers